# Closing another process listener

Tags: android, process

Is there any possibility to create a listener for closing another process?

Let's say I want to know when the process `com.android.test.app` isn't running anymore.

By the way, I don't want to use threads for listening for current running apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Btw I don't want to use threads for listening for current running apps.

From what I know, there is no other way supported by Android as yet.

---

I'd like to point out that [getRunningAppProcesses()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses%28%29) checking processes with  `IMPORTANCE_EMPTY` or  `IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND` is one of doing this but as per the documentation :

> Note: this method is only intended for debugging or building a user-facing process management UI.